# Reading conditions from a text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in the form:

```
CONDITION IF (abc) IN (abcd)
#Do something
CONDITION ELSE
#Do something
CONDITION END
```

I need to write a script in python where it will read the string and the moment it encounters 'CONDITION IF (abc) IN (abcd)' (the condition wont be the same everytime) it will execute the next line and if the condition is False, it will go the 'CONDITION ELSE' and execute that following part. After executinf, it will come CONDITION END.

What I have done is:

```
    def check_condition(var_str):
        line=var_str.split(" ")
        #Takes the condition
        cond=" ".join(line[2:])
        flag=True
        if cond:
           print ("True")
        else:
           print ("False")
```

But its showing terminated in the console.
Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how that class relates to what you're trying to do. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are the statements after the conditions valid Python? Although unsafe and not the best approach, you might want to take a look at [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: @MatiasCicero Yes the condition are valid in python, but its in the form of string.